# How to read values from a JSF session map in a servlet filter?

Tags: session, authentication, servlets, jsf-2, servlet-filters

To authenticate with my Java EE webapp I have a **login.xhtml** JSF page associated with a **LoginBean**. The LoginBean saves a value into a session map, if the users has given valid login details:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("session-value", true);
```

Now I want to read that value (called "session-value") in a **LoginFilter** (implementation of javax.servlet.Filter) but I everytime I try to access the attribute, the console tells me that the attribute is null:

```
 @Override
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws Exception {
    HttpSession session = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getSession();
    Object attribute = session.getAttribute("session-value");

    if(attribute != null) {
      LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, ":)");
    } else {
      LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Attribute is null.");
    }

    chain.doFilter(request, response);
  }
```

Is it not possible to access the JSF session map with a call to the session of an HttpServletRequest?

Answer (score 0):

First, yes you can access the JSF session map in a regular filter or servlet. It is in the underlying session and not specific to JSF.

The FacesServlet which handles your login.xhtml (presumably you have the web.xml faces related configurations correct), is processed after your servlet filter, not before. If you are testing the variable, the messages you see are null because the page has not logged in the user yet.

If you are looking to write a force login type filter (checking for something in the session and redirecting to a login page when the item is missing), then you want to exclude the actual login from the filter. The spec does not support exclusions in the url mapping, but you can add code to your filter like this:

```
        HttpServletRequest req = ((HttpServletRequest)request);

    if (!req.getRequestURI().contains("login")) {
        //...Process your login code here - force redirect
    } //Otherwise it will allow the next filter or first servlet to process
```

After the login page processes and the next page is requested (action or forced navigation), the filter will process again and your value will be set.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But when the JSF session map stores the values in the underlying session then it should be possible for my access filter to read that values from the session if the filter is hit a second time after a login has been made? Because when I hit the filter a second and a third time, then the values read from the session are also null. :(

Comment: Yes you will be able to see the 'true' value on all subsequent executions of the filter. The code snippets you posted are solid assuming they are executing. Storing items into the session during the JSF lifecycle and retrieving them later (in the same session) outside of the FacesServlet context is standard practice. There are lots of code samples that look pretty much like yours. I would just add as much messaging as possible around that code that stores the value. Try retrieving it back out in the same LoginBean before it finishes executing whatever other code you have in place.

Comment: Ok. I did that. First, the filter is executed, then writes the JSF page a value in the session and then the session value is read by the next execution of the filter. However, the session seems to be empty on all susequent executions of the filter. Can it be that my bean or my JSF page clears the session? My JSF page uses a Bean with "Named" and "RequestScoped" annotations.

Comment: It sounds like you validated your original question and found that you can read session attributes written from JSF in a regular servlet filter. As to why subsequent calls of your filter stop showing the attribute, all I can suggest is you trace all your code and log that value over and over until you find where it is getting cleared. Also if you are calling anything like: FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().invalidateSession();, then yes, you are clearing your session.